Calculate running sum with upper limit ClickHouse
I would like to calculate a running sum in ClickHouse using window functions, but I'd like the running sum to not go above a certain value.
A hypothetical 'sumWithCeil' function:
SELECT t.groupId
     , t.value as probability
     , t.datetime
     , sum(probability) over (PARTITION BY groupId ORDER BY datetime ASC) as runningSum
     , sumWithCeil(probability, 1) over (PARTITION BY groupId ORDER BY datetime ASC) as desiredSum
  FROM myTable t

The above would produce results: Example numbers
I have also tried wrapping the "probability" value inside sum with the "least" function (i.e sum(least(probability, 1)) over ..). And similarly wrapping the whole line inside a "least". However, neither produce the same output as the "desiredSum".

Don't you want least() to apply after the summation?

I want it to apply during the calculation. I want each row to be aware of the result of the curtailed summations, not the summations then curtailed! These can produce different results

Of course they're different. (And aren't all your probabilities less than 1 anyway?) I think you should provide some example numbers.

I have added a few more rows to the examples in the attached image. (Probability here could be read as "value", I want a limited cumulative sum on value)

Ok, so it's the negative numbers that make it interesting.

Kindly try the below
    SELECT t.*,least(runningSum,1) from(    SELECT t.groupId
    , t.value as probability
    , t.datetime
    , sum(probability) over (PARTITION BY groupId ORDER BY datetime ASC) as runningSum

    FROM myTable t)t


Compute the running total. Then offset it looking backward for the peak value up to that point:
with dataX as (
    select *,
        sum(value) over (partition by groupId order by datetime) as cumv
    from T
)
select groupId, dt as "datetime", value as "probability",
      cumv - max(greatest(0, cumv - 1)) over (partition by groupId order by datetime)
from dataX
order by groupId, dt;

https://dbfiddle.uk/-AIyNRY9
